# Proof that Mersenne numbers with a composite exponent are also composite

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers

I'm following the book *The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths, and Programming*, and I am unsure of one of my proofs for one of the exercises.

It is to be proven that a number of the form
$M_n = 2^n -1$ is composite, if $n$ is also composite.

My proof goes like this: Assume there are $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n = ab$. The Mersenne number can be written as:

$M_n = 2^n - 1 = 2^{ab} - 1 = (2^{a})^b - 1 = (2^a - 1)^b$

Which is clearly divisible by $2^a - 1$, which in turn makes it composite.

So this is my solution, which is a lot simpler (at least im my opinion) than the solution given in the *Solutions to the Exercises*, which can be found [in this pdf](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/HR/JustSOL.pdf) on p. 22 (Exercise 3.36). But is my *proof* correct, as I'd expect the authors to use the simplest possible proof?

Comment: if you're using $(x+y)^\alpha=x^\alpha+y^\alpha$, without additional assumptions, this is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, of course! Sorry, I forgot that the exponentiation doesn't just distribute over the terms in the parens. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: $(2^{a})^b - 1 = (2^a - 1)^b$?????

Answer (score 3):

It is very much false that $(2^a)^b - 1 = (2^a - 1)^b$ (take, for example, $a = b = 2$, where the LHS is $15$ but the RHS is $9$). The correct statement is that

$$\frac{(2^a)^b - 1}{2^a - 1} = 2^{a(b-1)} + 2^{a(b-2)} + \dots + 2^a + 1.$$

This is just the sum of a finite geometric series.